# before save event, need help for looping two cells at the same time

Tags: vba, excel, before-save

I'm trying to do a beforesave event, not allowing users to save if one of two given cells are empty. What I managed to do so far is linking column 13 (M) and cell A4.

What I'd like to do is applying the event to a combination of two range and rows, A4-A19 and M4-M19. In this way: If A4 is not empty and M4 is empty, a msgbox appears and blocks saving and so on..A5-M5, A6-M6...until A19-M19. If both corresponding cells are empty at the same time, then saving should be possible.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

    Dim i As Integer, MyWb As Object
    i = 13
    Set MyWb = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Planning").Cells
    Do While MyWb(4, i).Value <> ""
    i = i + 1
    Loop
    If i = 13 Then
        If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Planning").Range("A4") <> "" Then
            MsgBox ("You will need to enter topics before saving"), vbCritical
            Cancel = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Based on Wolfie's code, I managed to obtain what I wanted, just adding a If not isempty for A column and replacing 19 instead of 13.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

Dim plansht As Worksheet
Set plansht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Planning")

' Loop over rows
Dim rw As Integer
For rw = 4 To 19
    ' Test if both the A and M column in row "rw" are blank
    If Not IsEmpty(plansht.Range("A" & rw)) And plansht.Range("M" & rw).Value = "" Then
        MsgBox ("You will need to enter topics before saving"), vbCritical
        Cancel = True
    End If
Next rw

End Sub
```

Comment: The code you've created from my answer checks: "If Ai is not empty and Mi is empty then ...", note that the `Not` only applies to the first condition before the `And`! I'm not sure if that's what you want?

Comment: yes it is exactly what I wanted, when I got your first answers I realised that my original request was not correct...in reality I wanted exactly this behaviour: if A is not empty and M is empty  then.......:)

Comment: Ah okay, thanks to be of help, I've edited my answer for some notes on using the logical operations :)

Comment: Thanks. it's useful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop over the rows, and just test the `A` and `M` columns to test if they are both blank for a given row. See the below code...

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

Dim plansht as Worksheet
Set plansht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Planning")

' Loop over rows
Dim rw as Integer
For rw = 4 to 13  
    ' Test if both the A and M column in row "rw" are blank
    If plansht.Range("A" & rw).Value = "" And plansht.Range("M" & rw).Value = "" Then
        MsgBox ("You will need to enter topics before saving"), vbCritical
        Cancel = True   
    End If    
Next rw

End Sub
```

---

**Edit:**

Your edit suggested you want some different combinations of the cells being empty. Here are some examples of the `If` statement for different outcomes

```
' If BOTH are empty
If plansht.Range("A" & rw).Value = "" And plansht.Range("M" & rw).Value = "" Then ...

If IsEmpty(plansht.Range("A" & rw)) And IsEmpty(plansht.Range("M" & rw)) Then ...

' If EITHER is empty
If plansht.Range("A" & rw).Value = "" OR plansht.Range("M" & rw).Value = "" Then ...

If IsEmpty(plansht.Range("A" & rw)) Or IsEmpty(plansht.Range("M" & rw)) Then ...

' If BOTH are NOT empty
If plansht.Range("A" & rw).Value <> "" And plansht.Range("M" & rw).Value <> "" Then ...

If Not IsEmpty(plansht.Range("A" & rw)) And Not IsEmpty(plansht.Range("M" & rw)) Then ...
```

Notice that when you start introducing `Not` with multiple conditions, the logic can quickly become hard to interpret. You can use brackets to group conditions with a `Not`, but you get things like this meaning the same logically:

```
If Not IsEmpty(plansht.Range("A" & rw)) And Not IsEmpty(plansht.Range("M" & rw)) Then ...
If Not (IsEmpty(plansht.Range("A" & rw)) Or IsEmpty(plansht.Range("M" & rw))) Then ...
```

Comment: I've just realised that my description was not correct, what I'm trying to do is the opposite. I edited the description.

Comment: For either being empty (instead of *both*) just use `Or` in place of `And`! :)

Comment: Thanks, it's true :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
For i = 4 to 19
    If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Planning").Range("A" & i) <> "" AND _
       ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Planning").Range("M" & i) <> ""  Then
          MsgBox("Hey bro you didn't wrote properly on line " & i)
          Cancel = True

Next i
```

Comment: `For 1 = 4 to 19` should probably be `For i = 4 to 19`. Typos are fun!  :)

Comment: Thanks for this typo :)

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

    Const FIRST_ROW as integer = 4
    Const LAST_ROW as integer = 19
    Const ColA As Integer = 4
    Const ColM as integer = 13
    Dim MyWb As Worksheet
    Dim CurRow as Integer

    Set MyWb = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Planning")
    For CurRow = FIRST_ROW to LAST_ROW
      If len(mywb.cells(CurRow, ColA)) = 0 and len(mywb.cells(CurRow, ColM)) = 0 then
        MsgBox ("You will need to enter topics before saving"), vbCritical
        Cancel = True
        Exit For
      End If
    Next
End Sub
```

*Untested code* (I can never remember if it's (Row,Col) or (Col,Row)), but I think that will get you what you're after. This will abort the save on the first pair where they're both blank.

If this works, you could get fancy and *highlight* the blank pair(s), *remove* the highlight for OK pairs (in case they were highlighted previously), processing through all the pairs and removing the `Exit For` and providing one error message that anything highlighted needs to be looked after.

I've been told that `Len(string) = 0` is a faster way to determine that a string is null than `string = vbNullString`. No guarantees as to suitability to purpose, but that's what I've learned.

Comment: It works but I realised that my description is wrong...I will edit it.

Comment: You're correct, it is `Cells(row, col)`, easy to remember because it's the opposite of `Range` ;-)  You can also reference within `Cells` by column letter, so instead of `ColA` and `ColM` you can just use `"A"` and `"M"` :)